# Working with multiple rows in table as properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, linq-to-sql, system.data.sqlite

I'm working with sqlite databases using System.Data.Sqlite library. I have the "metadata" table, which looks like this:

[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PI6s.jpg)

It doesn't always contain all of these rows and fields, and there can also be a lot of optional ones.
Usually I work with these fields as properties (which I get through reading queries and reflection), my class:

```
class MetadataTable
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public MetadataTable(string pathToDb)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={pathToDb};Version=3;"))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to open database.");
            }

            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT key, value FROM metadata;";
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();
                    List<string> propertyValues = new List<string>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        propertyNames.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                        propertyValues.Add(reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.Count; i++)
                        propertyNames[i] = propertyNames[i].ToLower().First().ToString().ToUpper()
                                         + propertyNames[i].Substring(1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < propertyValues.Count; i++)
                        typeof(MetadataTable).GetProperty(propertyNames[i])?.SetValue(this, propertyValues[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And how it's called from Main():

```
string pathToDb = "D:/Downloads/mytest.db";
MetadataTable metadataTable = new MetadataTable(pathToDb);
Console.WriteLine($"Version:{metadataTable.Version}, Author:{metadataTable.Author}, " +
                  $"Timestamp:{metadataTable.Timestamp}, Location:{metadataTable.Location ?? "Not specified"}");
```

Recently I decided to try LINQ to SQL and written a simple class for my table:

```
[Table(Name = "metadata")]
class Metadata
{
    [Column(Name = "key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

That's how I read it in Main():

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={pathToDb};Version=3;"))
{
    using (DataContext context = new DataContext(connection))
    {
        Table<Metadata> metadataFields = context.GetTable<Metadata>();
        foreach (Metadata metadataField in metadataFields)
            Console.WriteLine($"Key:{metadataField.Key}, Value:{metadataField.Value}");
    }
}
```

I find it very convinient, but is there same convinient way to work with rows/fields as properties (like in MetadataTable code above) without using reflection?

And BTW, is EntityFramework more suitable (and more performant?) for that task? I didn't work with LINQ to Entity or LINQ to SQL before, so it doesn't make big difference what to learn first.

Comment: nothing is stopping you to map even multiple rows to different properties, you'll just have to match the corresponding rows of your dataset yourself. The way you describe your schema being pretty dynamic does not suggest the use of an ORM. If the structure of the data you want to retrieve is pretty fix you may just ignore all properties not matching to a database column, however you should note that the use of an ORM is usually a performance hit, rather than a gain. EF does support a pretty dynamic approach for model generation, however I'm not sure if it is suitable for you.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro So you're saying, that the first descrbed approach is more performant? What I'm doing in my program, is a loop for a pretty big amount of dbs, like thousands of them. I get all properties from every one (and as I said, at that moment I don't know which rows are exist in db), do some mathemagics, change properties, and after all the databases are read, I create the db containing all the properties in it.
i don't really know, if the first approach is better for that, but the ORM looks much more convenient. But the main point is the performance of course.

Comment: What is "convenient" about your `MetadataTable` class? Your statement "there can also be a lot of optional ones" invalidates this class as a suitable container of all possible properties. You should ask yourself the question why you use this EAV layout for a fixed set of properties. Then, whenever variable properties are involved you'll find out that you'll always need some sort of pivoting to display them decently.

Comment: @GertArnold I was talking about `Metadata` class when I meant convinience, but I understood the point of what you're talking. Probably it would be better for me to use Dictionary<string,string> here instead of properties?

Comment: I don't know. It all depends on what you need the data for. I do know that you should try to avoid EAV as much as possible.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider creating a class based on `DynamicObject`? Instead of reflection, this uses runtime lookups that you write. Note: If you refer to a non-existent property for a particular table, you will get a runtime error. Perhaps you should show more of the code that loops through the databases and transfers the properties to another db? It isn't clear from your question what you need or even what reflection has to do with it.